# String CompareTo not working

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I have a simple if statement that doesn't seem to work. I'm out of ideas. I don't understand why my logic is wrong.

```
String a = "bf";

if (a.compareTo("bf"))
{
    // do this
}
```

I'm getting a redline under the `compareTo` statement.

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean`

Comment: Use `a.equals("bf")` instead. Or `a.compareTo("bf") == 0`.

Comment: `compareTo` return an int not boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`compareTo`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm) method returns int value. so do as

```
if (a.compareTo("bf") == 0)      
{
    //
}
```

(or)

use `.equals` method

```
if (a.equals("bf"))

{
// do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

compareTo returns an int, not a boolean.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html

It a negative integer if this instance is less than another; a positive integer if this instance is greater than another; 0 if this instance has the same order as another.

So you should check for `== 0`

By the way, it works for things that can be ordered only. If you just want to check for equality, use .equals

Answer (score 1):

change it to this

```
String a = "bf";  
if (a.compareTo("bf") == 0)      
{
 // do this     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `compareTo` method returns an `int` value, not a `boolean`.

You must change it to

```
if (a.compareTo("bf") == 0)
```

or use

```
if (a.equals("bf"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> When comparing for equality you should use equals(), because it
>   expresses your intent in a clear way.
>
> compareTo() has the additional drawback that it only works on objects
>   that implement the Comparable interface.
>
> This applies in general, not only for strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` method of `Object` class to **compare** two `String` objects here.

```
String a = "bf";

if (a.equals("bf"))
{
    // do this
}
```

**Moreover** `compareTo()` is the method of `java.lang.Comparable` Interface.

Answer (score 1):

compareto returns an integer. An if statement wants a boolean to check so change you code to:

```
String a = "bf";

if (a.compareTo("bf")==0)
{
  // do this
}
```